# Multiplying a number proportionally

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to create a formula for a weather-related task. I need the output to reflect the current temperature.

My range of temps is about $-15C$ to $+35C$, with outputs from $0.2$ to $0.7$. For example, the inputs and outputs should roughly be:

\begin{array}{c|lcr}
T & \text{Y} \\
\hline
35 & 0.2  \\
25 & 0.3 \\
15 & 0.4 \\
5 & 0.5 \\
-5 & 0.6 \\
-15 & 0.7 \\
\end{array}

Obviously a temp of $10C$ would result in $0.45$, $12.5C$ would be $0.475$, etc.

Can anyone please advise how I would multiply the temperature to produce the output I need?

Thanks

Comment: So what you want is a formula that matches the temperatures to the outputs?

Comment: Why don't you plot the numbers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T$ be the temperature and $x$ be the output. $x$ is a linear function of $T$. So

$$x=A+BT$$

for some constants $A$ and $B$.

Substitute $T=35$, $x=0.3$.

$$0.2=A+35B$$

Substitute $T=25$, $x=0.2$.

$$0.3=A+25B$$

Therefore,

\begin{align}
0.2-0.3&=35B-25B\\
-0.1&=10B\\
B&=-0.01
\end{align}

and hence

\begin{align}
0.2&=A+35(-0.01)\\
A&=0.2+0.35\\
&=0.55
\end{align}

$x=0.55-0.01T$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Given the table of values of inputs (T) and outputs (Y):

\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{T} & \text{Y} & \\
\hline
35 & 0.2 \\
25 & 0.3 \\
15 & 0.4 \\
5 & 0.5 \\
-5 & 0.6 \\
-15 & 0.7 \\ 
\end{array}

Notice that the ratios of differentials are the same:
$$\frac{\Delta Y}{\Delta T}=\frac{0.3-0.2}{25-35}=\cdots=\frac{0.7-0.6}{-15-(-5)}=-0.01.$$

Now obtain the linear function:

$$\Delta Y=-0.01\Delta T \Rightarrow Y-Y_1=-0.01(T-T_1) \Rightarrow$$
$$Y-0.2=-0.01(T-35) \Rightarrow$$
$$Y=-0.01T+0.55.$$